# What is the substitute of LPAD of SQL in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I want to convert the below query which is in vertica to PIG.

**SQL Query**

> SUBSTR(LPAD(A,13,' '),1,1) AS A13

*(A is an varchar variable)*

There is no LPAD built in function available in PIG.Is there any way I can code this in PIG without writing an UDF.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a SQL query to a mapReduce job it might be more convenient to switch to [HIVE](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) as it supports most common SQL commands.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do it this way :

```
REGEX_EXTRACT(
    CONCAT('             ', A),
    '(.{13}$)',
    1
);
```

First you suffix A with 13 spaces.
Second, you extract with a regex the last 13 characters.

However, if you're more confortable with SQL, prefer HIVE.

Comment: The requirement is in PIG,although it is much simpler in HIVE. I tried the above logic,but its not working as per my requirement..  Suppose the A = 'X'  So in SQL SUBSTR(LPAD(A,13,' '),1,1) will give me NULL and SUBSTR(LPAD(A,13,' '),13,1) will give me 'X'.I checked and didn't get the same with REGEX_EXTRACT.COuld you guide me on this?

Comment: If you want to change the size, you can adjust the 13 in the regex, to get less characters. If regex doe not match, it will return NULL so it should match the LPAD behaviour.